# Activity lifecycle?

Tags: android, android-activity, bundle, lifecycle

I think my ideas on activity lifecycle and bundles
are a little confused,can you help me?

Let's suppose the user opens **activity A** from home screen,
**activity A** "calls" **activity B** which fills the screen.
On this event `onSaveInstanceState()` is called on **activity A** then `onPause()` and `onStop()`.
Since there are too many apps currently running on the system,
andorid decides to kill the process hosting **activity A**.

When the user navigates back to **activity A**,onCreate() is called an we can
use the bundle ( setted during the last call of onSaveInstaceStae() ) to restore the state.
then `onStart()`,`onRestoreInsanceState()`
and `onResume()` are called,
am I right?

Then lets suppose the user presses back key to exit from **activity A**
`onPause()`,`onStop()` and `onDestory()` are called in sequence on **activity A** (the call  of `onDestroy()` could be postponed though)
`onSaveInsanceState()` should not be called  in this scenario.

When the user opens again **activity A** later on then the bundle
passed to **onCreate()** is null,right?

Now Suppose the user rotates screen
`onSaveInsanceState()` ,`OnPause()` ,`OnStop()`, `OnDestroy()` are called
then `onCreate()` with bundle setted by the last call to `onSaveInsanceState()`,
and then onStart(), and onRestore().
am I right?

My guess is that:

when the user creates an ativity,the bundle passed to `onCreate()` is always null and `onRestoreState()` is never called,but when the system creates it , for instance when it killed the activity because of low memory  or because of a rotation event,the bundle passed is the one setted by the last call of onSaveInstanceState().

Is my guess right?

thanks and sorry for my poor english.

P.S. : I think `onRestoreInstanceState()` is passed the same bundle is passed `onCreate()` but typically state is restored using `onCreate()`.

Comment: You may have to wait several days to get a good answer, not a few minutes..

Comment: I'm an android beginner,didn't Know my question was so hard...

Comment: You talk about Activities calling another Activity, but, it you add flags to the intent like "Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT" the onCreate method will not be called if the Activity was not killed by the system

Comment: @SeRPRo My question is about android standard behaviour,not special cases.

Comment: @user986437 OK I thought you were having troubles with your code, not a general programming question.

Comment: Check [this answer related to activity life cycle](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8516056/265167), this may help you i guess!

Comment: @user986437 we are seeing the same problem where the state is never restored correctly.  tried different permutations but no luck and so tend to agree with you.  how did you resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question - never thought about it.

Take a look at the documentation, [`onCreate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) and [`onSaveInstanceState()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29).

This answers at least your question what Bundle will be supplied to `onCreate()`.

Unfortunately there is no exact definition on which events `onSaveInstanceState()` is called, but I guess it is called by default in all relevant situations (whatever they may be...), but you can find out for some situations (e.g. rotating the screen) by putting a Log.i() to LogCat.

Answer (score 0):

onRestoreInstanceState() is passed the same bundle is passed onCreate() is right, and the system restart the activity by call onCreate() and also call onRestoreInstanceState(),the bundle will be null if get from onCreate() when the activity first started.

Answer (score 0):

> Since there are too many apps currently running on the system,
> andorid decides to kill the process hosting activity A.

This is a very common situation. Furthermore - you can emulate this action using developers option.

[image]

In this case each activity, that was move into background, will be automatically destroyed.

## About Bundle in OnCreate .

I can get from my memory only two cases when OnCreate will be called with non-null Bundle. First - described above. Second case - screen rotation.

When you launch app Android calles

- onCreate
- onStart
- onResume

After that lets doing screen rotation. Android will call

- onSaveInstanceState
- onPause
- onStop
- onDestroy
- onCreate
- onStart
- onRestoreInstanceState
- onResume

The more information you can find on topic about [recreating](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)